# Vk.com javascript sdk ReferenceError: easyXDM is not defined

Tags: javascript, vk

I'm working on vk.com application, but I got an error at very first :( could anyone help please. 
I use both:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/xd_connection.js?2"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then I got error:

```
ReferenceError: easyXDM is not defined
VK._Rpc = new easyXDM.Rpc({
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: The `easyXDM` is not defined in `xd_connection.js`, there must be some other js you have to include.

Comment: Thank you, but I dont know what it is when the document only give xd_connection.js :|
    http://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK

Answer (score 0):

You rename your window name (window.name). So VK don't use this for XDM. Don't rename window, if we want use VK JavaScript SDK in your iframe-application.